# In Ansible, how can I print the values from my yaml file?

Tags: ansible

I tried doing the following but I knew it wouldn't work as it displayed the last value from the file. Is there a way to build a list from the `item.key` from my YAML file?

```
- name: Install PHP modules
  command: sudo rpm -Uvh {{ rpm_repository }}/aria-{{ item.key }}-{{ item.value.svn_tag }}.rpm --force
  with_dict: deploy_modules_php
  register: php_command_result

- name: set color success
  when: php_command_result|success
  with_dict: deploy_modules_php
  set_fact:
      color="green"
      msg="Successfully installed PHP RPMs! {{ item.key }}"
```

Looking for something like this in Hipchat (i'll deal w/ format once I can get it to work).

```
Successfully installed PHP RPMs! module1 module2 module3
```

I get ...

```
"Successfully installed PHP RPMs! module3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registered variable `php_command_result` should hold a set of all items where each should have nested properties like `changed` and in case the task has failed a `failed` property.

It's hard to do this blind, so this probably will not work immediately:

```
Successfully installed PHP RPMs! {{ php_command_result.results | rejectattr("failed") | map(attribute='item') | join(', ') }}
```

If it doesn't work, please post the complete output of `php_command_result`.

Comment: `php_command_result` is pretty large, here's the pastebin I just have a snippet of it. http://pastebin.com/EZCw21V6  Also, i tried what you suggested but it tells me `fatal: [127.0.0.1] => Failed to template color="green" msg="Successfully installed PHP RPMs! {{ php_command_result.results | rejectattr("failed") | map(attribute='item') | join(', ') }}": template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'`

Comment: That's strange. `map` should be a default Jinja 2 filter. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map

Comment: Looks like I need to run v2.8.

Comment: Nice! So i upgraded Jinja to v2.8 and it works except I had to remove `rejectattr("failed")` because it's telling me `One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'failed'`